# UIButton does not show on iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I have a UIButton that doesn't appear only in iOS 9.3.

I don't understand why. Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

I need the button in the ViewDidAppear method as I have some other layout elements that need to be placed after this button is set.

> iPhone 6 8.1 Button Settings Location: {{100, 100}, {42, 42}}
>
> iPhone 6 9.3 Button Settings Location: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
>
> iPhone 6Plus 8.1 Button Settings Location: {{100, 100}, {42, 42}}
>
> iPhone 6Plus 9.3 Button Settings Location: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}

```
#define MARGIN_SIZE  10
@interface HomeViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIButton *btnSettings;
@end


- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.btnSettings = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.btnSettings.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.btnSettings.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 42, 42);
    self.btnSettings.tag = 21;
    [self.btnSettings setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_black"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btnSettings addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.btnSettings];

   NSLog(@"Button Settings Location: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.btnSettings.frame) );

}
```

Comment: Change the property from `weak` to `strong`. Any difference?

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. I don't know how I didn't catch it. That fixes the issue. But why did it work in 8 but not 9?

Comment: I always go weak for IBOutlets and strong for all UIElements created by code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There appears to be a difference in memory management between iOS 8 and 9. Your property is weak. It doesn't get a strong reference until you add the button as a subview with the call to `[self.view addSubview:self.btnSettings];`.

It seems that under iOS 9, the weak reference is deallocated (and the property set to `nil`) before that call is reached. But under iOS 8, the weak property sticks around long enough for that line to be reached preventing it from being deallocated.

The simple solution is to make the property `strong` instead of `weak`.

Another option (thanks Jef) is to keep the property `weak` but use a local variable in your `viewDidAppear` method. Then assign the local variable to the property after adding the local variable as a subview.

One other unrelated issue with your code. If this view controller shows other view controllers then the `viewDidAppear:` method will be called more than once and you will end up adding multiple buttons. Either move this code to `viewDidLoad` (where it really belongs anyway), or ensure the code in `viewDidAppear` is only called one time for the life of the view controller.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. You're exactly right about why it gets lost but I think a better solution is to use a more temporary strong pointer - UIButton *aButton = ...... ; ......//button config; [self.view addSubview: aButton] ;//button is now retained as part of view hierarchy.. self.settingsButton = aButton

Comment: @Jef That's not a disagreement, that's a perfectly good alternative to making the property `strong`.

Comment: I only say so because it has less impact on the big picture design, memory management etc. best :)